# netstate -lput doesn't show the pid of deamon that is listening on port:8080?

Tags: port, pid, netstat

I runed:netstat -lputn to find ount which program is listening on port 8080,but got blow output:

[image: no pid or program info got shown]

As you can see no pid or program name got shown,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
ps -ef|grep 8080
```

It turns out jenkins